# g++ in Cygwin stoull is not declared in this scope

Tags: c++11, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile a library from https://github.com/simongog/sdsl-lite and I am not able to compile.

I am using g++ 4.8.3 and the message that I got from compilation is that stoull was not declared in this scope:

This is the code that is throwing the error:

```
uint64_t _parse_number(std::string::const_iterator& c, const std::string::const_iterator& end)
{
    std::string::const_iterator s = c;
    while (c != end and isdigit(*c)) ++c;
    if (c > s) {
        return stoull(std::string(s,c));
    } else {
       return 0;
    }
}
```

I have tried with different flags: c++0x, c++11 and gnu++11 but without success.

Do you have any clue how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @quantdev I already tried adding the std prefix but without success. I could solve it by changing to the C version of this function: strtoull.